# Control the pagination of Flutter swiper

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using this dependency: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper

How could I control when I want to move to next slide element?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `SwiperControl`or `SwiperController` to control your current element. To prevent swiping you can pass `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to `physics` property.

Full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  SwiperController _controller = SwiperController();
  int _i = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Swiper(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Image.network(
            "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          );
        },
        itemCount: 3,
        pagination: SwiperPagination(), 
        controller: _controller,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _controller.move(++_i % 3);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but I can still swipe the pages without the controls

Comment: it should be an option I guess to not drag elements on the swiper

Comment: Would you consider using other paginating widgets? This widget might not be the best option for you. MaterialRoute or other widets might help.

Comment: Updated the answer, take a look. But consider using other widgets too.

Comment: I can play with `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` and use here somo condition but the problems is that I should be able to swipe back. For example, I could be on 3rd step and I should cancel the swipe to 4rd but I should be able to go back and also to move forward from 1 to 3. I don't mind to use a different widget but `MaterialRoute` would change the route right?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a `SwiperController` in your state and set it to the swiper. Later you can call `next` or `previous` to change the page programmatically.

You can check the official documentation for more details: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper#controller

```
class _ExampleCustomState extends State<ExampleCustom> {
  SwiperController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = new SwiperController();
  }

  void _someCallback() {
    _controller.previous(animation: true);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Swiper(
      controller: _controller,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can call `next` or `previous` already, but I don't know how to avoid the swipe between elements using a normal finger swipe

Comment: how can we add .move() in controller In layout: SwiperLayout.STACK , it doesnot work in normal condition?